# Python Read/Parse Account:Password txt file line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

So I essentially have an accounts.txt file with accounts I created which look like this:

```
Richard:Milo:RichardMilo@email.info:0495612970
Adrian:Clark:ClarkAdrian283406@email.info:0490714484
Michael:Robinson:13Mich@email.info:0446088017
Julio:Lucas:JulioLucas60@email.info:0454710033
```

As you can see they are in the format FirstName:LastName:Email:Phone

Put simply, what I want my python script to do is read each line, return **the first name, last name, email, and phone on each line** as the "email", "first_name", "last_name", and "phone" variables and then **delete that line entirely** then move on to the next line, do the exact same, then delete the line, etc etc. I already have the loop down pat it's just returning one part of each line which is giving me difficulty.

Here is my current python code:

```
submit_count = input('\nEnter Desired Number of Entries: ')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

def enterraffle():

    email = #NOT SURE HOW TO GET THE EMAIL FROM ACCOUNTS.TXT HERE
    first_name = #NOT SURE HOW TO GET THE FIRST NAME FROM ACCOUNTS.TXT HERE
    last_name = #NOT SURE HOW TO GET THE LAST NAME FROM ACCOUNTS.TXT HERE
    phone = #NOT SURE HOW TO GET THE PHONE FROM ACCOUNTS.TXT HERE

    driver.get(‘Login URL’)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(‘password123’)

    print('{}/{} Successful Raffle Entries ({} {}:{})'.format(i, submit_count, first_name, last_name, email))
    with open("entries_nl.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(first_name + ":" + last_name + ":" + email + ":" + phone + ":" + "\n")
        f.close()

    time.sleep(2)

    #DELETE THAT LINE FROM ACCOUNTS.TXT HERE

    driver.delete_all_cookies()

for i in range(int(submit_count)):
        enterraffle()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you show us the code? it is better to have a starting point.

Comment: please post the python code you have written and point out where you ran into trouble... i suggest you use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) (with `delimiter=":"`) to read the file.

Comment: @Netwave apologies, I forgot. My python code has been added

Comment: Please remove all code that is unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lines = []
fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone']
with open('accounts.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
    values = [x.strip() for x in line.split(':')]
    lines.append(dict(zip(fields, values)))
```

Comment: Ok this returns a big list which is great, so how would I go about grabbing say the 5th email from this list, and then deleting it from the same list?

Comment: 5th email: lines[4]['email'], then get and delete 5th email: email_5th = lines[4].pop('email')

get 5th email and delete 5th dict: email_5th = lines[4]['email']; del lines[4]

Comment: This answer doesn't delete the lines @123ang Not sure why you accepted this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module to read your csv file.

```
import csv

#Open the file
lines = []
with open('accounts.txt') as fp:

    #Create a csv reader on the file
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=":")
    #Iterate through each row
    for row in reader:
        lines.append(row)

print(lines)
```

The output will be

```
[
['Richard', 'Milo', 'RichardMilo@email.info', '0495612970'], 
['Adrian', 'Clark', 'ClarkAdrian283406@email.info', '0490714484'], ['Michael', 'Robinson', '13Mich@email.info', '0446088017'], 
['Julio', 'Lucas', 'JulioLucas60@email.info', '0454710033']
]
```

So the first email will be `lines[0][2]`

Then to delete the contents of the file, just open it in `w+` mode

```
#Open the file in w+ to delete all rows
filename = "accounts.txt"
f = open(filename, "w+")
f.close()
```

You can then use this output to your `enterraffle()` function

Comment: Ok great so say I wanted to grab the first email there, how would I do so and then delete that whole line?

Comment: Okay I added a function to delete all the lines at the end, generally it is a bad idea to read and write the file simultaneously, and it is also unpredictable! Please check the answer @123ang and let me know if any confusion :)